# Is it possible to invoke hardware interrupts from software?

Tags: kernel, interrupt

In C, system calls are invoked with `asm("int $0x80")`. Is it possible to invoke the IRQ registered with `request_irq` directly from software?
How?

PS: apic->send_IPI_self looks promising. Haven't yet tested it.

Comment: I've expected this question. To simulate HW interrupt for debugging, testing and demonstration. Now I use UART in loopback more for this. The target project is Linux Driver Template - https://github.com/makelinux/ldt/blob/master/README.md .

Comment: @Const Have you finally found a way to invoke hardware interrupts from software?

Comment: apic->send_IPI_all(IRQ0_VECTOR+irq);

see usage here: https://github.com/makelinux/ldt/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=apic

Answer (score 0):

From user software, I'd say no.  Maybe if you were the software you were talking about is in kernel mode, I'd say there would be a good chance of invoking an interrupt processor.

Comment: Sure in kernel mode. The question is "how?"